# How to share a Google Earth Engine APP that uses Planet images from the NICFI program?

Tags: google-earth-engine, authentication

I'm creating an APP in GEE that uses imagery from the NICFI Program in its processing. The problem is that to use these images it is necessary that the user has a registration. Assuming the user has a GEE account with permission to use NICFI program images.

Is there any way to form these credentials for use in the APP?